# Resizing custom bullets without changing the font size - Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to make some custom bullets in Word 2010 with the help of a picture. I thought if I made the picture the desired size everything would work out fun, but it didn't. The problem is that the bullets are always bigger than the text which is not what I had in mind.

So my question is, is there any way to properly size the custom made bullets or is there another way to create these so they are actually smaller than my text. If I change the font size of my text the bullets automatically become bigger as well. I would include an image but I don't have the sufficiënt reputation to do so.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use images as the "character" for a bullet, it is automatically sized to become 100% of the current line height.  If you want to make the bullet appear smaller then the text, you need to modify the original image and include more whitespace around the image.

Again, there's no programmatic way to do this, so you need to do it "by eye" so to speak.  If you're using Word to edit the image, you should be able to use the crop tool, and expand the image border.  If you're using a more advanced image editor, look for an option to increase the canvas size.

The advantage to this method is that your bullets will always appear smaller then the text size you set, regardless of how big.

Comment: Thank you, I'll mess around with the canvas. As soon as I can I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Highlight the bullets
2. Right-click
3. Select "Font..."

Then change the size on the far right side of the window by selecting smaller sizes.

It will change the bullet size, but not the font.

Answer (score 1):

You can also increase/decrease bullet size by:

1)  Highlighting the bullet

2)  Clicking on the Grow Font or Shrink Font buttons in the Font group. They are grouped to the right of the font type and size drop-down windows.